# why does "pkg_info -Q bash" on OpenBSD give me an "empty" result?

Tags: kvm-virtualization, proxmox, openbsd, bsd

i installed a fresh OpenBSD server on a Linux - Proxmox server with kvm.

I tried to to install bash but pkg_info returns "empty":

```
root@openbsd:~# echo $PKG_PATH
https://cdn.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD

root@openbsd:~# ping -c 1 cdn.openbsd.org
ping: Warning: dualstack.osff.map.fastly.net has multiple addresses; using 
151.101.2.217
PING dualstack.osff.map.fastly.net (151.101.2.217): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 151.101.2.217: icmp_seq=0 ttl=60 time=5.810 ms

--- dualstack.osff.map.fastly.net ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/std-dev = 5.810/5.810/5.810/0.000 ms

root@openbsd:~# pkg_info -v -Q bash   
PKG_PATH=https://cdn.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD
https://cdn.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/: empty
root@openbsd:~#
```

DNS / reverse DNS is good.

how can i debug this?

Answer (score 0):

The `PKG_PATH` variable is not set to the correct value.

In modern OpenBSD versions, you no longer need to specify a PKG_PATH, but if you want to, you need to include the full path to the packages, something like:

`https://cdn.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/7.0/packages/amd64/`